# How can I use S3 signed URLs with Facebook's Open Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, facebook-opengraph

I host video content on my website and use signed URLs to prevent hot-linking. The problem is when users share the video on Facebook, it only fetches the current URL. Once the URL expires, Facebook will not ping the page to see the new contents of the Open Graph meta tags.

Example
The source of the page reveals the following.

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://hackerbracket.s3.amazonaws.com/5370343b2e2862ad432d2b18-97423eaf1ab8690e4f91fdb725dbaf7c2a09dfd6-low.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIU7HRCRAOSCZTI6Q&amp;Expires=1406058260&amp;Signature=N43bR0ZY5I66WUVxRa7kQRm%2Bml4%3D&amp;t=.mp4" />
```

However upon refreshing the content is changed to the following.

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://hackerbracket.s3.amazonaws.com/5370343b2e2862ad432d2b18-97423eaf1ab8690e4f91fdb725dbaf7c2a09dfd6-low.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIU7HRCRAOSCZTI6Q&amp;Expires=1406058319&amp;Signature=9SnbPIAoKTHBsZill3i8JJyvEcs%3D&amp;t=.mp4" />
```

Note the `t=.mp4` because Facebook does not seem to like it when the URL does not end in MP4 which is the strangest thing ever.

Is there a way around this issue? I don't want my videos to be statically available. Maybe a way in S3 to allow Facebook's HTTP Referrer?

Comment: The content is served over HTTPS so I'm pretty sure that you will never get a referer.

Comment: @WizKid if both pages are HTTPS the header will be included.

Comment: @DavidL.Rodgers did you ever find a solution to this i am also having issues with facebook graph and Amazon S3 urls?

Comment: @user1503606 I finally gave up and decided to use an S3 bucket policy that only allows access to HTTP Referrer https://www.facebook.com. This fixes the issue with others embedding the video in their site while maintaining Facebook Open Graph embed.